# scrolling ul li right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help to fix this. I have two buttons (left arrow button and right arrow button). I will like to horizontally scroll my catalogued picture items from right to left and vice versa by clicking on either the right arrow button (i.e. to scroll the catalogue pictures right) or the left arrow button (i.e. to scroll the catalogue pictures left). I've got the following code:

```css
span.arrow-left,span.arrow-right,h3.m_1 span,h3.m_2 span {
    display: block;
    color: #434343;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
 float: right
}
span.arrow-left:hover, span.arrow-right:hover, h3.m_1 span:hover, h3.m_2 span:hover {
    color: #FFA200;
}

ul.product_grid{
 margin-top: 0.7em;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
 overflow: hidden;
} 
ul.product_grid li{
 width: 15.936%;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
ul.product_grid li img{
 border:8px solid #fff;
}
ul.product_grid li.last_product{
 margin:0;
}   
.product h3 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
 color: #434343;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<h3>Products
<span class='arrow-left'><i class="arrow_right_alt"></i></span>
<span class='arrow-right'><i class="arrow_left_alt"></i></span></h3>
<ul class="product_grid">
  <!-- I want to scroll horizontally items from here with the arrow buttons at the top-->
      <li><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i1.jpg" class="img-responsive"alt=""/></a></li>
      <li><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></li>
      <li><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></li>
      <li><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></li>
      <li><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></li>
      <li class="last_product"><a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog1"><img src="images/i6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a></li>
  
  <!-- And stop here -->
  
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div id="small-dialog1" class="mfp-hide">
     <div class="pop_up">
      <h4>Item Name</h4>
      <img src="images/i_zoom.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
     </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

Thanks

James

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I appreciate you want to do this with html, css and javascript, but have you considered using Bootstrap Carousel?  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: No. I'll check the link posted though. Thanks, James

Comment: I actually checked the link, but I don't want my catalogue image to scroll automatically. It should scroll onclick function (i.e. scroll to the right when I click the right arrow button or scroll to the left if I click on the left button). The two navigation button were placed at the top right corner above the catalogue images. Thanks, James

Comment: Check the documentation carefully...  Specifically the options: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-options  You can supply a value of `false` for the `interval` property and it will not scroll automatically.  The look of it is completely modifiable with CSS.